# Is it possible to use push_back() for entering elements into a 2-D vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I was learning about vectors and wanted to create a vector of vectors through user input. Although I have found a way to do that, I wonder if `push_back()` can be used for entering values in the vector.

As per the code:
`vec[i][j] = ele;`  works successfully but `vec[i][j].push_back(ele);` doesn't work.

I am unable to understand why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector<vector <int>> vec(n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        vec[i] = vector<int> (k);
        for(int j=0; j<k; j++) {
            int ele;
            cin >> ele;

            // =====================================================

            vec[i][j] = ele;  // Why does this work

            //vec[i][j].push_back(ele); // but this doesn't?

            // =====================================================
        }
    }

    int a, b;
    for(int i=0; i<q; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << vec[a][b] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provided i and j are valid, `vec[i][j]` is a single element not a std::vector. It would only make sense to push_back on this if your vec was 3D.

Comment: It would be `vec[i].push_back(ele);`. `vec` is a vector of vectors of ints. `vec[i]` is a vector of ints. `vec[i][j]` is an int.

Comment: lets break this down for a sec, vec is a `vector<vector<int>>` so vec[n] gives you? and what does vec[n][m] give you? Now ask yourself why vec[n][m].push_back(ele) doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks a @drescherjm. I understand it now.

Comment: Thank you @cdhowie.

Comment: Thank you @Borgleader for answering. I get it now :)

Answer (score 3):

As you have vector of vectors of integers, that means that expression `vec[i][j]` will return reference to an integer (because `vec[i]` is i-th vector and `vec[i][j]` is j-th integer in the i-th vector), that's because there is no error with assign expression (`vec[i][j] = ele;`), as you are assigning new value to the j-th element of the i-th vector. So if you want to add new element to the i-th vector you need to call `vec[i].push_back(ele)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand how it works, but for some reason, when using `vec[i].push_back(ele)`, my vector is printing out every element as `0`.

Comment: I suspect you still left this line in: `vec[i] = vector<int> (k);` and are printing `k` items per row instead of the size which will be 2 times that.

Comment: Great, I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: @PrabhuSharanSingh You are initializing your k length vectors with 0-es, then using `push_back` to add values inputted by the user, so I think as @drescherjm mentioned your `vec[i] = vector<int> (k);` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Similar to when you want to `.pushback()` in a 1D vector, you would only do `vec.pushback(ele)` instead of `vec[i].pushback(ele)`

When you do `vec[i][j].pushback(ele)`, you are actually adding element into 3rd dimension.

So in your case, you would want to `vec[i].pushback(ele)`

Answer (score 1):

`vec` is a vector of vectors of integers. So by calling `vec[i]` this will return the i-th index vector. Then calling `vec[i][j]` will return the j-th index integer in the vector `vec[i]`. You use the `push_back()` method on vectors to add values to the end of them. So by calling `vec[i][j].push_back()` you are trying to use the `push_back()` method on an integer, which does not make sense.